# iOS rtmp streaming

Tags: ios, streaming, rtmp

I want play rtmp link following:

rtmp://edgecast-fmstream.mndigital.com/mp3:/mp3/mn_mp3_12_02/downloads/a070/071/051/71051427_017?48d882e51ff49ca3806e4b63d90b926556349db16cecf61947afe79948feb8eda04e

This link play on Windows:

```
rtmpdump -r rtmp://edgecast-fmstream.mndigital.com -y mp3:/mp3/mn_mp3_12_02/downloads/a070/071/051/71051427_017?48d882e51ff49ca3806e4b63d90b926556349db16cecf61947afe79948feb8eda04e | vlc.exe -
```

How can do I in iOS project?
already I complied librtmp on mac for iphone?
How can use librtmp on iOS?

Comment: maybe your answer can be found in this duplicate question (with this extremely long URL) http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Wyf2FRcDltgJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/6042353/rtmp-stream-on-ios+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari